# .net 8 identity login with custom login endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-identity, .net-8.0

In .net 8 i understand that .MapIdentityApi and .AddIdentityApiEndpoints are added.
The issue is that they add a bunch of things i don't want.
For example you are not allowed to register, only admins can add new accounts.

The only endpoints i want are /login and /logout.

I assume this means i need to implement them manualy. but i can't seem to find any information about this. everything i find just tells me to use the ".AddIdentityApiEndpoints" and how great it is that this is added.

Where can i find information about this? so i can re-create the login endpoint?

Comment: You usually login via a web app and not an api.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you don't have a way to control that, if your going to use identity end points you will get all. check this great article about [identity end points](https://andrewlock.net/should-you-use-the-dotnet-8-identity-api-endpoints/).

If you want to control end point best solution will be adding asp.net identity to your api project and implement jwt your self, [check this repo](https://github.com/andissanayake/UnifiedApp).